# Are meta questions not considered for the hot questions list?

Tags: discussion, meta, hot-questions

I look at the Stack Exchange hot questions list fairly regularly, and I can't remember ever seeing a Meta Stack Exchange question.

Is Meta blacklisted (if so, why?), or are there simply not any questions here that are hot enough to get onto the list?

Comment: This is obsolete. Newest post is http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229777/200868

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are plenty of hot questions on Meta Stack Exchange.  But the sites ultimately are about quickly getting great answers to good questions related to the subject at hand.

Meta and the per site child metas are not about that.  They're about the inner workings of the network and its communities which, while they have great and essential value, are not the ultimate focus of the network.

Answer (score 11):

No metas are considered for the hot question list.

Comment: Why doesn't this question show up on the first page of results when searching Meta for "meta hot questions"?

Comment: It didn't @Jim because it wasn't tagged [meta-tag:hot-questions], which is why I missed it as well. This has now been fixed by Tim.