# Do we need MSE in the hot list?

Tags: support, hot-questions, meta

Apparently MSE questions are able to appear in the hot list, which the old MSO didn't managed to. Shouldn't MSE behave the same way as the old MSO in this aspect?

[image]

Comment: This question is now #44 in the hotlist. How ironic.

Comment: @michaelb958 I don't see the irony. I was only asking because it was strange that MSO didn't appeared, yet MSE does. I'm not taking sides.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Not anymore. We can now selectively feature select, network-relevant discussions on MSE on the entire network via [the Community Bulletin Board](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130892/nailing-it-up-on-your-community-bulletin-board) with the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag. They shouldn't appear in the hot list otherwise.

Comment: Even if the hot questions list does have one or two MSE posts, why is that bad? More people will regularly see what's going on here beyond just the announcements that are pushed. If anything, more people may pitch into discussions, which, considering that this site's discussions are relevant to multiple sites, seems to be a positive.

Comment: The nature of meta sites makes them significantly "hotter" than most normal sites: we're hosting discussions, after all. We could make it work, but a solution tailored to the need would be preferable.

Comment: Ach, don't tell me it's temporary!

Comment: @Shog9: so, just use a different metric for meta? seems reasonable. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218247/what-changed-in-the-hot-questions-sidebar-algorithm

Comment: _nature of meta sites makes them significantly "hotter"_ -- interesting how you use this to justify their total exclusion from hot list, but in the same time ignore similarities in the nature of [smaller / subjective-ish sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224750/165773) which are additionally exacerbated by weaker community moderation power there. Oh well

Comment: What makes you think I *ignore* this, @gnat? Open-ended discussions are *on-topic* for meta sites, so by their nature they require special treatment - but of course, such topics can crop up elsewhere, even if they're not encouraged, and I'm committed to making sure y'all have the tools available to redirect them as necessary.

Comment: your comment shows exactly what makes me think so. "Open-ended discussions" aren't the issue at sites I talk about (Programmers and Workplace), these are off-topic there, closed and dropped from the list - we already have good _tools_ to handle these thank you. Legitimate, on-topic, answerable questions can be "hotter" there (compared to SO), due to simple differences in topicality / voting patterns / moderation power. Really sad that you can't see this

Comment: You appear to be misunderstanding what I meant by "the nature of meta sites" then, @gnat.

Comment: no matter how you twist it, from the perspective of a [hotness formula](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192046/165773) that mysterious "nature of meta sites" can be described as "average more answers and higher score of the questions". Same can be said of typical (topical, answerable, not closeable) questions at smaller / subjective-ish sites

Comment: As much as you've tried to bury it, "subjective-ish" is the key description there, @gnat. I'm hardly unaware of how problematic such questions are - but pretending that a question anyone can answer is all fine and dandy as long as most people don't find it is just silly.

Comment: anyone ([of 16 million programmers](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/17640)) can answer SO questions as well, it's only their coding-oriented nature makes it easier to detect low quality / [repetitive](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2562) garbage and site scale makes it [easier to get rid of it](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2584). _Real questions have (authoritative) answers_ everywhere at SE network (maybe except for Code Golf, but their specifics makes it less of an issue, or maybe even not an issue at all)

Comment: As usual, [that quote is truncated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75168/should-polls-be-maintained-as-community-wiki-questions-or-should-they-be-closed/75179#75179) @gnat. "real questions have answers, *not items or ideas or opinions.*"

Comment: @Shog9 it's truncated only because of comment length limitation, adding "not items or ideas or opinions" keeps what I meant intact. "Answers" that are just _items, ideas, opinions_ are frowned upon at both Programmers and Workplace, and are eventually cleaned up - the only difference is it takes longer and is more painful compared to SO

Comment: So if you recall, we weren't talking about SO here @gnat - we were talking about Meta. We don't generally clean up opinions (or questions asking for them) here.

Comment: from the perspective of a hotness formula specifics of meta sites, just like one of smaller/subjective-ish ones can be described as "average more answers and higher score of the questions". As I said, it's interesting how this specifics is used at one hand to justify exclusion of meta from hot list but on the other hand isn't taken into account when it comes to non-meta sites

Comment: Ok, we're just going around in circles, @gnat. Nothing gets onto the hot list without the site it was posted on putting it there - if your site is putting up discussion questions and *isn't a meta*, you have a much more serious problem than the occasional appearance in a sidebar list. When you're ready to admit this, we can start solving real problems.

Comment: discussion questions are closed and dropped from hot list at Programmers and Workplace, I don't recall much issues with these. _Real problem_ is, bug in hotness formula tends to increase amount of manual community moderation / janitorial work at these sites and mis-guide SO users about what kind questions are welcome at SO. "Think of SO regulars (making probably the largest audience of the hot list), what do they learn from it? No matter how good are SO questions that get into the list, vast majority of what is promoted there is not like that..."

Comment: @gnat if you have a general gripe about the hot questions algorithm, start a new thread proposing a change (assuming you have an argument that hasn't been discussed here already). you guys are getting way too chatty here, and wandering away from the point of this post.

Comment: Admit it, this whole answer is just an excuse to use the word serendipitous. ;-)

Comment: Since it was decided against this, what were the reasons? The fact that its discussion-based or hotter than other sites doesnt really seem a good reason.