# "Hot Questions - Stack Exchange" feed including questions from MSE?

Tags: support, bug, hot-questions, feed

The [HNQ feed](https://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions) (a RSS feed for 30 of the HNQs) has questions from [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com), a site that is excluded [[1]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229780/278094), [[2]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316906/278094) from the HNQ list. 
[image: HNQ feed]
The strange thing is that those MSE questions are not in the regular [HNQ list](https://stackexchange.com).
How is this happening? Is there a separate check for HNQ and the HNQ feed?

Has the HNQ RSS feed for aye had MSE? *(Can more three letter words be in that sentence?)*

Is this a bug, or did I just discover a hidden feature?

Comment: The point of excluding some sites from the HNQ sidebar was because of a lack of context, attracting users to questions with unusual titles. There's no lack of context on the RSS feed, you have to subscribe to it manually. Let's not remove sites from the feed, please.